# bootstrap 4 slider carousel multi carousel inner

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make all the carousel inner slide by group at the same time when I click the menu of slide 3?

I try to use bootstrap carousel to control all the item slide at the same time but I found it's not working for me. anyone knows?

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">slide 2</li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">slide 3</li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/slide4.png">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/slide5.png">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/slide6.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/slide7.png">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/slide8.png">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/slide9.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO3kI.png)